# Change background on element with multiple background images

Tags: css, background, responsive-design, dynamic-css

I have used CSS background on multiple divs to create a number of large format buttons. It looks beautiful, but the buttons are created dynamically, and there could be thousands of them. This means a HUGE dynamic CSS script... it there a better way of giving each element a different CSS background with the same properties?

here is the example code - HTML:

```
<div id="ab_a" class="banner_button">           
     <h2>Title A</h2>`
</div>

<div id="ab_b" class="banner_button">       
     <h2>Title B</h2>`
</div>

<div id="ab_c" class="banner_button">           
     <h2>Title C</h2>`
</div>
```

etc.... (there could be several thousand of these)

The CSS:

```
#ab_a {
      background: 
    linear-gradient(
      rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0),
      rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6)
    ),
    url(../images/bgimageA.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    width: 100%;
    padding-bottom:37.01%;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}
#ab_b {
      background: 
    linear-gradient(
      rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0),
      rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6)
    ),
    url(../images/bgimageB.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    width: 100%;
    padding-bottom:37.01%;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}
#ab_c {
      background: 
    linear-gradient(
      rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0),
      rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6)
    ),
    url(../images/bgimageC.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    width: 100%;
    padding-bottom:37.01%;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}
```

...I don't want to have to repeat this block of code 1000's of times in a dynamic CSS file.

How can I separate the background url (the only bit which changes) from the rest of the code?

BTW - Putting just the background url inline within the script will not work, it will ignore all the CSS properties in the stylesheet.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yeah..just got that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using **multiple background images** on a single element,  unfortunately, there's no way using pure CSS to set the second background image in a separate rule **without repeating all the previous background layers**.

jQuery to the rescue.
***[jsFiddle demo in action](https://jsfiddle.net/90vrw719/)***

Inside your CSS set the second background to `none`:

```
.banner_button{

    background: linear-gradient(
      rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0),
      rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6)
    ), none  50% / cover;  /* notice the `none` for the second layer */

    width: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 37.01%;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}
```

while creating your elements, make sure to generate them passing the desired image URL from whatever data you use, >> inside a `data-*` attribute of your generated element:

```
<div class="banner_button" data-bg="../images/whatever.jpg"></div>
```

Than using jQuery, replace that `none` value with the value holded by the `data-bg` attribute:

```
$(".banner_button").css("backgroundImage", function(i, v){
  return v.replace("none", "url("+ $(this).data("bg") +")" );
});
```

That's it.
**jQuery will rebuild the whole background layers for you!**

Comment: Genius! This is exactly the solution I needed! I was surprised i couldn't find this anywhere else on StackOverflow, would have thought it would be quite common these days. Works perfectly. Thanks hugely!

Comment: @Leon well, actually neither did I found any answer on that matter... No problem, you're welcome